# jquery select list and $_POST help

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a select list, currently I have it implemented then when the user selects an item, the I have some javscript that creates a `li` on the fly on the places on the page, the problem is that I want the user the be able to select multiple items from the list, however the javascript cannot cope with this, but I need this functionality so that when I submit the form the values of the selct list go into the post.

Currently my javascript looks like this,

`$('#sector').change(function() {
            var selected = $(this).val();
            //alert(selected);
            $('#selected_sectors').prepend('<li>'+selected+'</li>');
        });`

Is it is possible to get this each time the user ctrl+selects and item is creates the li but and keeps the values accesible in the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly something like this is what you're looking for (note the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector).

```
<select id="items" multiple size="5">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="grape">Grape</option>
</select>
<ul id="sel-items"></ul>

$('#items').change(function(e){
    $('#sel-items').empty();
    $(this).find(':selected').each(function(i,e){
        $('#sel-items').append($('<li>').text($(e).val()));
    });
});
```

[**Working Example**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/fczP2/)

(Working on one now that checks for deltas between the `<select>` and the `<ul>`)